# How to call Microsoft Graph from non-MVC Web app c#

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've got an existing ASP.NET web app which is non-MVC and I would like to get it to call the Microsoft graph. I read up on the ASPNET MVC tutorials and got those to work but I am looking for some code samples of calling the Microsoft Graph that don't use MVC or OWIN to acquire an access token. This is because I would like to avoid rewriting my entire app into MVC. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a number of samples on Github. [Here's a console app one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console).